# How to make one app go through OpenVPN?

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvpn

I have a Raspberry Pi that I use to host my websites at home, and I would like to use it as a torrent server too. How can I make one app traffic (the torrent server) go through OpenVPN without redirecting all the traffic, which would prevent me from accessing the hosted websites with my public IP.

Comment: 1. don't set the default route to go via the VPN. 2. configure your torrent software to use the IP address given to you by the VPN.    Alternatively, run the torrent software in a container or VM and configure the container/vm to use the VPN as its default route.

Comment: NOTE: details of how to do this are beyond the scope of a single question, as there are many different methods and many variables involved.   If you have specific questions about specific problems you're having with configuring some part of this, feel free to edit this question or ask another.

Comment: That's exactly what network namespaces were invented for. I suggest you search for "openvpn network namespace" and narrow down your question to the actual problems you encounter when trying to make it work. (fwiw, you don't need to run any vm or full containerization suite)